# Angular js filteration by check box

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I need to filter results by check box weather ng-repeat contains simillar text  values.
Here is code snippet
    http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/

```
$.inArray(names.slotschedule, $scope.colourIncludes)
```

is there any function similar to contains of array

```
$scope.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
if ($scope.colourIncludes.length > 0) {
    if ($.inArray(fruit.colour, $scope.colourIncludes) < 0)
        return;
}
```

In this i need to filter by array contains text which i pass in ng-click
example
 if i pass 're' in ng-click include parameter red color should be filtered.

Comment: First, never user jquery with angular.. angular already has a jqLite version.  You should filter this using the filter service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945861/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-angularjs-and-use-a-property-of-the-filtered-objec

Comment: thanks for suggestion @Fals here i need to check with sequence of letter contains or not.but not complete word.any suggestions for check box filtration.