# Angular JS - Box score filter - should this be a function or a filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that calculates scores.  One of the keys in the scores data is 'period'.  I would like to present a box score by period and team in the view.

I need to filter and sum my scores data by team and period.

.length would do this in the view pretty easy if I had data filtered to an expression.  My question after reading MANY post on similar challenges is - where is the best place to do this filtering?

I am able to do an ng-repeat on the scores and filter by team but I then need to filter again by period.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945861/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-angularjs-and-use-a-property-of-the-filtered-objec).  And am trying something similar in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PTVhqdxZQ3LPT2UYlSaD?p=preview) but it doesn't seem to be working as I hoped.

```
  $scope.homeScores = $filter('filter')($scope.scores, {team:'home'})[0];
```

Feels like it should be simpler to achieve...

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="score in (filteredItems = (scores | filter:{team: 'home', period:3}))">
      <li>{{ score.period }} - {{score.team}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Scores: {{ scores.length }}</p>
    <p>Home Scores: {{ filteredItems.length }}</p>
  </body>

</html>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.scores = [
    {team: 'home', period: 1},
    {team: 'away',period: 2},
    {team: 'home',period: 2},
    {team: 'home',period: 3},
    {team: 'away',period: 3},
    {team: 'home',period: 3}
    ];


});
```

Comment: Thanks Sheetal.  It only looks like the second filter is being applied.  How could I apply them both?  Team and period.

Comment: edited the answer please check, a little confused with you question, you need filtering or grouping?