# How to get distinct values from JSON based on Foriegn Key using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, foreign-keys, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm having two JSON Array, $scope.data has the primary details, which I want to show in the UI, in that `cInstId` is the `foreign key` from the JSON $scope.color.

The two JSON Arrays are

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "cTitle": "One",
        "cInstId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cTitle": "Two",
        "cInstId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "cTitle": "Three",
        "cInstId": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "cTitle": "Four",
        "cInstId": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "cTitle": "Five",
        "cInstId": 4
    }
];

$scope.color = [
    {
        "cInstId": 1,
        "cInstTitle": "Blue"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 2,
        "cInstTitle": "Green"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 3,
        "cInstTitle": "Red"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 4,
        "cInstTitle": "Orange"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 5,
        "cInstTitle": "Violet"
    }
];
```

My expected output should be as like the picture

[image]

```
<div ng-repeat="members in data">
    <!-- How to Show it in the UI -->
</div>
```

> Note: Don't create any temp array and for-each implementation in the
>   Controller.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Show us the code.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh Kindly assist me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom filter here for this.

```
angular.module('ModuleName').filter('color', function($filter) {
  return function(id, colorArray) {
    return $filter('filter')(colorArray,{'cInstId': id})[0].cInstTitle;
  };
});
```

Use this filter as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="members in data">
    <!-- How to Show it in the UI -->
    <span>{{member.cInstId | color:color}}</span><!--Second color is your scope var -->
</div>
```

> Note: I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945861/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-angularjs-and-use-a-property-of-the-filtered-objec) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

But it will be better if you can create your color service and use that service instated of using the array directly.

Comment: Look at my custom filter here it is caling angular filter and passing your colors array. It is also passing your provided id to find the exact color here.

Comment: It is possible, using of $scope.color instead of manual feeding JSON in the ColorService ???

Comment: YES then you need to pass the array as filter input. as follows~ <span>{{member.cInstId | color:collorArray}}</span>~.