# How to use an object that is filtered by its properties in angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-interpolate

I am illustrating a stacked graph along with its table and fetching its json data with `$http.get()` and setting it to `$scope.dataset`

html:

```
<input ng-model="_searchQuery.key1.key2">
<tr  ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataset | filter:_searchQuery ">
```

I how can I update `$scope.dataset` in controller?

`_searchQuery` matches `dataset` and filters my table like charm. no need to code any thing in controller. ie `dataset.key1.key2` reflects to `_searchQuery.key1.key2`

but for my nvd3.js stacked graph I have to filter the `$scope.dataset` the same way in DOM. `$scope.dataset = $filter('$scope._searchQuery.key1.key2')($scope.dataset)` throughs an err. Im following angular documentation and this link: [How to use a filter in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller?rq=1)

Comment: Any reason you are using interpolate instead of just injecting $filter into the controller?

Comment: @Sasang same result with the filter. is there any clean way to do it without using ng-change and calling $scope.apply every time?

Comment: Are you using the nvd3 library directly? If so consider using the angular directive for it: `angular-nvd3`. In this case, just change the graph dataset when you receive/select new data, then call the refresh method on nvd3 3 attribute: ` $scope.api.refresh()` . You wouldn't need to trigger anything on ng-change or use scope.apply

Comment: thanks for guid. let me check.

Comment: @Sasang there is too much to change using angular directive. cannot do that for now. any other idea? does _searchquery updates the $scope.dataset or just filters the result? not sure how this form of filtering works in angular.

Comment: Cab you update your question to include some more code, maybe a basic view and controller so i can fiddle with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142668/discussion-between-sasang-and-dragonknight).

Comment: @Sasang if you have a look at this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties) I am filtering the $scope.dataset object by its multiple properties. but I cannot use that filter in the controller to update the chart. it only reflects to DOM not controller. here i am stucked.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a possible duplicate question [How do I filter an array with AngularJS and use a property of the filtered object as the ng-model attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945861/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-angularjs-and-use-a-property-of-the-filtered-objec)

same solution worked for me:

first: I had to instantiate `$scope._searchQuery` in `controller` as an `object` and include its properties.

second: update the `$scope.dataset` - and the keyword for filter by object property is `filter` which I was playing around with `_searchQuery`

the syntax helped me to fix the problem: 
`$scope.dataset = $filter('filter')($scope.dataset,$scope._searchQuery.key1.key2);`

It looks its not possible to pass more than 2 args to $filter, thus to filter based on more inputs I had to copy the same line and pass `$scope._searchQuery.key1.key3` to it.