# Filter data from array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, mapping

I have 2 `arrays` and I want to filter data based on column value. I am using below code but It is not working.

```
const result = data.map(data1 => {
            return Object.assign({}, data1, this.data2.filter(data2 => data2.Id !== data1.Id)[0]);
        });
```

**Data 1 :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "data 2",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "data 3",
  }
]
```

**Data 2 :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "data 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "data 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "data 4"
  }
]
```

It should return below output.

```
[
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "data 4"
}
]
```

How do I solve this ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what are your input arrays are and what output you expect?

Comment: @Eeks33 check updated post.

Comment: So, you want to keep all the objects in data2 that don't exist in data1 (and use their ID to know if they exist or not in data1), is that right?

Comment: @JBNizet, yes. right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: So you don't need any Object.assign. All you need is data2.filter(element => !elementExistsInData1WithId(element.id)). I'll leave the implementation of elementExistsInData1WithId as an exercise. Array.some() is useful.

Comment: Check this for ES¨: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639411/4654957

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a difference of 2 arrays of objects, see: [Difference between two array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/difference-between-two-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

You can also go by pure ids like this:

```
let ids = data1.map(item => item.id);
let filteredData = data2.filter(item => ids.indexOf(item.id) === -1);
```